# What does the filed "installed" in Facebook graph "me/friends" specify

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the code bellow to get the list of all of users friends and check how many of them have installed the app so i can show their scores, and unlock some content for the user.

I can't find solid info about the field installed which seams to be perfect for this case.(If it specifies the user has installed the app which made the request :) )

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/friends"
                                 parameters: @{ @"fields" : @"id,installed"}
                                 HTTPMethod:nil
                          completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                              id result,
                                              NSError *error) {
                              if (!error) {
                                  // Get the result
                                  NSArray *resultData = result[@"data"];
                                  // Check we have data
                                  if ([resultData count] > 0) {
                                      // Loop through the friends returned
                                      for (NSDictionary *friendObject in resultData) {
                                          // Check if devices info available
                                          if (friendObject[@"installed"]) {
                                              //Do some work if user has installed my game
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(void)FBFriendList
{
    if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        // if the session is closed, then we open it here, and establish a handler for state changes

        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,FBSessionState state, NSError *error)
         {
             if (error)
             {
                 UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:error.localizedDescription delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                 [alertView show];
             }
             else if(session.isOpen)
             {
                 [self FB_Common_Friend];
             }

         }];

        return;
    }
}


-(void)FB_Common_Friend
{
    FBRequest *request =  [FBRequest  requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:@{@"fields":@"name,installed,first_name,picture"} HTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error)
     {

         NSLog(@"%@",result);
         int count = 0;
         NSMutableArray *frnd_arr = [result objectForKey:@"data"];
         for (int i = 0; i < [frnd_arr count]; i++)
         {
             if([[[frnd_arr objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"installed"] boolValue])
             {
                 count++;
             }
         }
         app.fb_frnd_count = count;

     }];
}
```

Comment: So you are confirming my speculation that field installed specifies that friend has installed my app? :)